# How to click a button on another webpage using vb

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net, button

So I have a webpage that opens a browser window for the user to fill out a form. Currently when the user clicks my save button it saves the data and closes the window that was just opened. What I would like to do is also have it click a refresh button on the original window using vb code. jquery would work, but I prefer vb.

Here is the button I have to click:

```
<asp:Button ID="refresher" runat="server" Text="Refresh" Visible="False" />
```

I saw somewhere someone said to try:

```
web.document.getElementbyid("")
```

but it said document was unrecognized.

Comment: _"jquery would work, but I prefer vb."_ - nope, you're interacting with the browser, you need JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: It's not the refresh button on the browser, its a button that runs some vb to update the page. Does you comment still hold for this?

Comment: You want two rendered pages to interact. The serverside is done processing by that time. You need JavaScript for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access javascript functions on the parent window (your original window). For instance, parent.myRefreshFunction()

Comment: So I created a function to test this that runs onclick="" for a input button on the opened window. function refresher() { window.parent.clickRefresh(); } and it didn't run the function clickRefresh() in the parent window. Does it matter that the window is a webpage? sorry i didn't put it in code blocks, kinda new to stackoverflow.

Comment: So when i asked for the parent window location it was the new window that I had opened up. The page I'm originally at is TrainingSignOff.aspx, and I open up TrainingSignoffWindow.aspx. when I do alert(window.parent.location); it gives me the TrainingSignoffWindow.aspx

Comment: Have you tried using the console to see what error is returned?

Comment: when I open the new window this is how I do it.               window.open('TrainingSignOffWindow.aspx', 'targetWindow', 'toolbar=no,location=no,status=no,menubar=no,resizable=yes,width=1000,height=800,top=100,left=100')

Comment: Well you got me going down the right path, I used window.opener.clickRefresh(); and it worked. Thanks for the push in the right direction.

Comment: Parent refers to the parent of a window in a <frame> or <iframe> and opener refers to the window that called window.open. Glad you made it work.